# How to segment a 3D data automatically?

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, 3d-printing, segmentation

I have a data `dataCube`, which consist of some floating stones and a circular belt. I want to get the 4 biggest stones from the image, and segment out the outer belt and other noises (e.g. small stones etc.).

```
id = "7ea03ea6b5df8acae178578dd80eca8af42e1cd16df8d4eea370599d649e5a89";
dataCube = BlockchainGet[id];
myColorFunction = (If[# == 0, Transparent, Hue[#, 1, 1, 0.1]] &);
Show[Image3D[dataCube, ColorFunction -> myColorFunction, 
Method -> {"VolumeLighting" -> "EnhancedEdge", "InterpolateValues" -> True}], 
Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, Background -> Black, Axes -> True, 
AxesLabel -> {Style["z", Bold, 16], Style["y", Bold, 16], Style["x", Bold, 16]}]
```

[image]

A semi-automatic approach (e.g. build-in machine learning function which can group the components together based on the connectivity of the pixel) for the task would be preferred since I have plenty of this kind of images to be segmented. I tried `ImageForestingComponents` in the following way, but the result is bad:-

```
img3D = Image3D[dataCube, ColorFunction -> myColorFunction, 
Method -> {"VolumeLighting" -> "EnhancedEdge", "InterpolateValues" -> True}];
ImageForestingComponents[img3D] // Colorize
```

How get I get it done? Many thanks!

Comment: `MorphologicalComponents` and `ComponentMeasurements` comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks! `abc = MorphologicalComponents[dataCube]; abc2 = 
 abc /. x_ /; x != 1 -> 0; Image3D@abc2` give me the largest stone!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw.: Performancewise, you might want to replace the rule-based approach for selecting subsets with `abc2 = abc (1 - Unitize[abc - 1]);`.

Comment: Thanks! So I summerize it as `abc = MorphologicalComponents[dataCube]; label = {1, 6}; abc2 = Total[abc*(1 - Unitize[abc - #]) & /@ label]; Image3D@abc2`.

Comment: And you can find the (indices) five largest components (by the number of their elements) with `Reverse@Ordering[Values@ComponentMeasurements[img, "Count"], -5 ;;]`

Comment: Take a look at [THIS](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1646303)